how wo use the .xml file in the tilesheet with godot 2d tileset?
I'm trying to build an isometric tilemap. I downloaded an isometric resource from Kenney, but the size of each tile is different, and each tilesheet provides an xml file to represent their size. How should I use it? to build my tilemap?
the kenney assets i download
tilesheet looks like this

the xml file looks like this

my godot version is v4.2.1.stable.official [b09f793f5]
I need a way to be able to build this type of tilemap, thanks everyone

maybe this similar question might help

thaks pal, It seems that this problem cannot be solved yet
